# Do I have to use references in C++.?

Tags: c++

I have a kinda deep C experience but I am a C++ beginner. References seem to be easier to use than pointers, but it drives me crazy. I think all references can be replaced with pointers. In my case, pointers are not that hard because I spent tons of times studying them. Is it common among C++ programmers to use references or is it just recommended??

Comment: IMO references vs pointers is a style issue, and as such, there is no right answer.

Comment: In some cases (like copy constructors and some overloaded operators), references are necessary. But if you know pointer really well, I don´t see why it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that references prevent is `NULL` pointers. If you want to ensure that a parameter passed to a function is not NULL, you can pass by reference.

```
void func(int& i); // i cannot be NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

References *cannot* always be replaced by pointers:

```
C a, b, c;
a = b - c;
```

If there is an `operator-()` for `C`, it either needs to receive its arguments:

- by copy:

  ```
  C operator-(C left, C right);
  ```
- by address:

  ```
  C operator-(C* left, C* right);
  ```

  in which case the call becomes:

  ```
  a = &b - &c;
  ```

  (which already has a meaning in C)
- or by using a new construct that has no equivalent in C. This became references in C++.

There are a [variety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/4885801) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/745878/4885801) you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3224155/4885801) to [concerning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4288030/4885801) the use of references versus pointers.